# COUNT() returns the total number of rows in the grouped table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I have two tables:

Job table:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

FailedReason table which is referenced to the Job table by :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

My goal is to compute the failure ratio based on the failure reason.

My expectation is to get a result with the first column containing the `failure reason name`, the second column containing the `total number of all jobs` ('successful' + 'failed'), the third column containing the `total number of failed jobs` caused by the reason, and the fourth column containing the `failure ratio` calculated using the following formula: failed count (3 column) / total count (2 column) * 100.

My sql query :

```sql
SELECT
  FailedReason.main_reason as "Failure reason",
  COUNT(job.name) AS "Total jobs",
  SUM(CASE WHEN job.status='failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Total failed jobs",
  SUM(CASE WHEN job.status='failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(job.name) * 100 AS "Failure ratio"
FROM job
LEFT JOIN FailedReason
ON job.id=FailedReason.job_id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

And I get the result where the total number of jobs from the aggregated table is counted. As a result, the failure rate is one hundred percent.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

What should I modify to get the correct number of jobs ('succeeded' + 'failed') and calculate the correct ratio value

Sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE failedreason (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  job_id INT REFERENCES job(id),
                  main_reason varchar(255)
                 );



INSERT INTO failedreason (job_id, main_reason) VALUES (13095427, 'test case failure'),
                                    (13095407, 'test case failure'),
                                    (13095533, 'connection error'),
                                    (13095546, 'connection error'),
                                    (13098367, 'runner connection error'),
                                    (13101522, 'script error');

CREATE TABLE job (id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                  created_at date,
                  finished_at date,
                  status varchar(255)
                 );
INSERT INTO job (id,
                  created_at ,
                  finished_at ,
                  status
                 )
VALUES (13095427,  '2021-05-03 02:50:41', '2021-05-03 03:47:27', 'failed'),
       (13095407,  '2021-05-03 02:50:39', '2021-05-03 03:46:41', 'failed'),
       (13095533,  '2021-05-03 02:50:41', '2021-05-03 03:47:27', 'failed'),
       (13095546,  '2021-05-03 02:50:41', '2021-05-03 03:47:27', 'failed'),
       (13098367,  '2021-05-03 02:50:41', '2021-05-03 03:47:27', 'failed'),
       (13101522,  '2021-05-03 02:50:41', '2021-05-03 03:47:27', 'failed');
       (13101444,  '2021-05-03 02:50:41', '2021-05-03 03:47:27', 'success');
       (13101445,  '2021-05-03 02:50:41', '2021-05-03 03:47:27', 'success');
       (13101446,  '2021-05-03 02:50:41', '2021-05-03 03:47:27', 'success');



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYnPg.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3baS.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC7Hp.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not giving correct total and so % are not proper.

Please try this one

```
select reason, alltotal, failed,
    failedtotal,
    cast( (100.00 * failed /failedtotal) as numeric(10,2)) failedRatio , 
    cast( (100.00 * failed /alltotal) as numeric(10,2)) failedPercent from 
    (SELECT
      FailedReason.[main_reason] reason,
      MAX(tots.total_jobs)  alltotal,
      MAX(ftots.total_failed)  failedtotal,
      COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN job.status='failed' THEN job.id END) failed
    FROM job, FailedReason,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_failed FROM FailedReason) ftots , 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_jobs FROM job) tots
     where job.id = FailedReason.job_id 
    GROUP BY FailedReason.[main_reason]) finaltable
```

Result on shared Sample query data

[image]

Comment: This query returns the error 'Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'numeric(10,2))/total) * 100 as numeric(10,2)) failedPercent from (SELECT fa' at line 2'

Comment: you can remove casting and just try failed/total * 100

Comment: without cast, query returns integer value and so result is 0, better you cast it. or you can use like (100.00 * failed/total)  failedPercent

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any way to calculate the ratio connection_error_jobs / total_failed_jobs * 100 ? So the ratio of the jobs failed under each group reason. For example `connection error jobs` count is 2. `Total failed jobs` here is 5. So the `ratio `should be 40%

Comment: Updated query to get Ratio i.e. 2/6 and percentage i.e. 2/9

Answer (score 0):

Count the unique jobs, and rollup to get totals.

> ```
> SELECT
>   CASE WHEN GROUPING(job.status) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE job.status END AS `Job Status`
> , CASE WHEN GROUPING(fail.main_reason) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE fail.main_reason END AS `Failure Reason`
> , COUNT(DISTINCT job.id) AS `Total Jobs`
> , COUNT(DISTINCT job.id) / MAX(tots.total_jobs) * 100 AS `Ratio`
> FROM job
> CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_jobs FROM job) tots
> LEFT JOIN failedreason fail
> ON job.id = fail.job_id
> GROUP BY job.status, fail.main_reason WITH ROLLUP
> ORDER BY GROUPING(job.status), GROUPING(fail.main_reason), `Ratio` DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> Job Status | Failure Reason          | Total Jobs |    Ratio
> :--------- | :---------------------- | ---------: | -------:
> success    | null                    |          3 |  33.3333
> failed     | connection error        |          2 |  22.2222
> failed     | test case failure       |          2 |  22.2222
> failed     | runner connection error |          1 |  11.1111
> failed     | script error            |          1 |  11.1111
> failed     | TOTAL                   |          6 |  66.6667
> success    | TOTAL                   |          3 |  33.3333
> TOTAL      | TOTAL                   |          9 | 100.0000
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad93013ec1ad78c59576a30f4b1f699d)*

Comment: Same result. The count is applied to the grouped table.

Comment: Ok, well... if they have a main_reason, then they are a failure. So grouping on main_reason will have total jobs = total failures.

Comment: See update, cross join and using it in the ratio

Comment: I checked the updated query. Now the number of total jobs and total failed jobs is still equal to each other but the ratio is the odd value.

Comment: But should "Total Jobs" be `MAX(tots.total_jobs)`? What results do you expect?

Comment: I expect to get the count of all jobs ( succeeded + failed ). For instance i have 2 succeded job in the jobs table and 5 failed. so the total column should be 7, failed column - 2 and the ratio is 71%.  ratio is a result of 5/7 * 100. Could you please check the  sample date from the issue description ? I hope it will help to test. THank you!

Comment: Now with fiddle and rollup

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`

```
SELECT f.main_reason AS "main reason",
       COUNT(*) AS "Total jobs",
       SUM(CASE WHEN j.status='failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Total failed jobs",
       (SUM(CASE WHEN j.status='failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS "Failure ratio"
FROM job j
LEFT JOIN failedreason f ON j.id = f.job_id
GROUP BY f.main_reason
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97014e8307bbafd9a4cc5a39115596be)

Comment: This query gave me the same result

Comment: please enter sample data About 15 records

Comment: Please check the sample data

Comment: @shapale I edited the answer according to the sample data. I think it works right now. Use SUM instead of COUNT

Comment: It returned the same result

Comment: I feel your question is not clear. Exactly what output do you want? Please enter the sample data with all possible combinations and specify the desired output of the sample data.